# Select specific part in file name

Tags: python

For example the files come in this format.

```
JasperReports - 14000369-ITR-2022-ORIGI-Recibo.pdf

JasperReports - 14000369-ITR-2022-ORIGI-Declaracao.pdf

JasperReports - 13079980-ITR-2022-ORIGI-Recibo.pdf

JasperReports - 13079980-ITR-2022-ORIGI-Declaracao.pdf
```

The part that needs the name is the one that has this 8-digit code "14000369", as it is what identifies each document, when I get that name I need to create a folder and move the files to it and move to the next file, the folder contains more than 400 files, with different codes so I want to automate, that's what I've managed to do, I'm starting in python.

```
from importlib.resources import path
import os
import os.path
from pathlib import Path
caminho = r"C:\Users\amanda.regina.PROCONT\Desktop\move\itr"
lista_arquivos = os.listdir(caminho)

for arquivo in lista_arquivos:
    print(arquivo)
#lista_arquivos = os.listdir(caminho+"\itr")
path = Path(caminho)
for arquivo_nome in path.glob('*13079980*'):
    print(arquivo_nome)
```

Comment: to clarify, you want to create a directory for each identifying number (e.g. "14000369"), then move all files that contain that number in the filename to the directory?

Comment: yes, because they refer to properties so it is necessary to separate by code

Answer (score 0):

If the file names are always in this format, you can use `.split()` to extract the number and then create the directory with `os.mkdir()` and move the files there with `shutil.move()`:

```
import os
from shutil import move

files = ['JasperReports - 14000369-ITR-2022-ORIGI-Recibo.pdf',
         'JasperReports - 14000369-ITR-2022-ORIGI-Declaracao.pdf',
         'JasperReports - 13079980-ITR-2022-ORIGI-Recibo.pdf',
         'JasperReports - 13079980-ITR-2022-ORIGI-Declaracao.pdf']

for f in files:
    number = f.split('-')[1].strip()
    os.mkdir(number) if not os.path.isdir(number) else None
    move(f, number)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
from shutil import move


src = "path-to-folder"
for f in os.listdir(src):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(src, f)): # you can check here for .pdf type
        code = f"{f.split('-ITR-')[0].split(' - ')[1]}"
        dir_path = os.path.join(src, code)
        if not os.path.exists(dir_path):
            os.mkdir(dir_path)
        # you can add here extra check to do not move if 
        # the file exists in dir_path
        move(f"{os.path.join(src, f)}", f"{dir_path}")
```